# Can't install Revel (Unrecognized import path)

Tags: go, package, revel

I'm a beginner in Go and I would like to use the Revel web framework.
I installed: Git; Mercurial and even: Bazaar and CVS.

I checked my environment variables. I set environment variable GOPATH to D:\Go and added D:\Go\bin to PATH.But I still get these errors when I ***go get The Revel Framework*** (*go get github.com/revel/revel*)

**

- package golang.org/x/net/websocket: unrecognized import path "golang.org/x/net/websocket"
- package gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1"**

Comment: Don't set GOROOT if you have. What is the output of `go env`? You also may have an old version of git (or maybe go). What is the output of `git version` and `go version`?

Comment: I deleted GOROOT but I still have the same problem.
Here is the output of go env: 
C:\windows\system32>go env
set GOARCH=386
set GOBIN=
set GOCHAR=8
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=386
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\MixaMo\Documents\Go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_386
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m32 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1

-The output of git version:
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
-Te output of go version
go version go1.4.2 windows/386

Comment: Try setting the GOBIN ? Also your GOROOT is still set and does not match what you mentioned above ?

Answer (score 2):

For instalation of GO into your home folder you need this environment variables:

```
.
├── bin
├── go (GO)
└── src
    ├── revel.project
    │   ├── app
    │   │   ├── controllers
    │   │   ├── models
    │   │   ├── routes
    │   │   ├── tmp
    │   │   └── views
    │   │       ├── admin
    │   │       ├── App
    │   │       ├── errors
    │   │       └── users
    │   ├── conf
    │   ├── messages
    │   ├── public
    │   │   ├── css
    │   │   │   └── administrator
    │   │   ├── img
    │   │   ├── js
    │   │   └── uploads
    │   │       └── 1
    │   ├── resources
    │   ├── scripts
    │   ├── test-results
    │   └── tests
    ├── code.google.com
    ├── github.com
    │   ├── revel
    │   │   ├── cmd
    │   │   ├── modules
    │   │   └── revel
```

run this in your prompt path or modify if your folders are differents.

```
  export GOARCH=amd64
  export GOPATH=~/go
  export GOBIN=~/go/go/bin
  export GOROOT=~/go/go
  export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/go/bin
  export GOTOOLDIR=~/go/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64
  export CC="gcc"
  export GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
  export CXX=g++
  export CGO_ENABLED=1
```

Where ~ is the name of you personal folder in the system (Bash Gnu Linux)