# Can't install Revel on MacOS "package gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1: unrecognized import path"

Tags: go, package, revel

Following "[Getting Started](https://revel.github.io/tutorial/gettingstarted.html)" directions:

```
$ go get -v github.com/revel/revel
Fetching https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1?go-get=1 (status code 404)
package gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1: unrecognized import path "gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1" (parse https://gopkg.in/fsnotify.v1?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
```

MacOS High Sierra version: 10.13.3 (17D102)
git version 2.14.3 (Apple Git-98)
go version go1.10 darwin/amd64

Previous similar problems (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33202323/golang-revel-freezes-when-download-gopkg-in-fsnotify-v1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29843116/cant-install-revel-unrecognized-import-path)) did not provide a solution that works.

Comment: That repo no longer exists, so `gopkg.in` can't redirect you there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed in [revel 0.19.1](https://github.com/revel/revel/releases/tag/v0.19.1)